# PyQt6: DB connection established but SQL query not executed

Tags: pyqt, pyqt6

I am trying to connect to a SQLITE3 database and the connection is getting established however, the query is not getting executed.

dbcon.py

```
from PyQt6 import QtSql
from PyQt6.QtSql import QSqlDatabase

class dbCon:
    def createConnection1(con1):
        con1 = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        con1.setDatabaseName('Bolt.db')
        con1.open()

        if con1.open():
            print("db connection created")
            return True
        else:
            print("db connection creation failed")
            return False
```

checkactiveapi.py

```
from PyQt6 import QtSql
from PyQt6.QtSql import QSqlQuery
from PyQt6.QtSql import QSqlDatabase
from models.dbcon import dbCon

def checkIfApiParamsAreActive(user):

    con1 = 'conVal'
    userInDb = 'userID'

    if dbCon.createConnection1(con1):
        print("Database Connected")
        qry = QSqlQuery(QSqlDatabase.database(con1))
        qry.prepare("SELECT * FROM LOGIN_PARAMS WHERE USER = :user")
        qry.exec()

        if qry.isValid():
            print("Query executed")
        else:
            print("Query Failed")

        """
        while qry.next()
            userInDb = qry.value("USER")
            apiValidity = qry.value("API_TOKEN_VALIDITY")
        if user==userInDb and apiValidity=='True':
            return True
        else:
            return False  
        """
```

To check if the query is fetching proper value, I commented out the code after `while qry.next()` and used `isValid()` and it is printing "Query Failed" every-time. I am suspecting it could be because of the sql query and the way I have used the where clause.

Any inputs would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Upon researching a bit, I found out that for prepare statements, direct arguments can not be used. They need to be bound to a local variable before the query is executed. Not sure  if this is the right approach at this moment. Need to read a bit more.

New line in checkactiveapi.py after prepare statement:

`qry.bindValue(':user',user)`

and uncommented the code from `while` loop onwards.

Comment: QSqlQuery::isValid() returns true if the query is currently positioned on a valid record; otherwise returns false.

Comment: Successfully executed SQL statements set the query's state to active so that isActive() returns true.

Comment: Other than that your `con1` starts as a string in `checkIfApiParamsAreActive`, then you use it as a `QSqlDatabase` in `createConnection` then you use it again as a string. Despite that, `qry = QSqlQuery(QSqlDatabase.database(con1))` succeeds returning your connection as a default connection, even though  the documentation says it should return an invalid connection. It even works if I use `QSqlQuery(QSqlDatabase.database('bogus'))`. I have no idea why that is.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on `isValid()`. If I do not initialize the con1 as a string, I am getting error `name 'con1' is not defined`. Can I directly use a variable to create the connection?It does not seem to work though. Must be something missing in the code. I am new to PyQt, so trying to wrap my head around stuff whenever something new comes up.

Comment: There are many issues with your code: 1. first of all, the `con1` argument of `createConnection1()` in `dbcon.py` is completely useless, since you're overwriting it at the very first line; 2. don't call `con1.open()` twice (it's theoretically harmless, but still useless); 3. `query.prepare()` accepts a simple string: that `:user` placeholder doesn't magically read your `user` variable, you must use `bindValue()`; 4. boolean values should be stored as integers in SQLITE, not literals (which may be prone to false negatives for case mismatch); alternatively, use lower strings (`false`, `true`);

Comment: 5. unless you have *multiple* databases, the database argument in QSqlQuery constructor is useless, as the first, main connected database is always considered as default for new queries; 6. for the same reason, there is no need for a class and function like that, unless it's intended for *multiple* databases: functions are for *reusability*; 7. that last `if` in `checkIfApiParamsAreActive()` should be in the same level as the while loop; 8. assuming you properly bound the `user` value in the query as written above, the `qry.value("USER")` will obviously be valid, so checking it is pointless;

Comment: 9. `checkIfApiParamsAreActive()` should have a final `return False`, in case the connection was not established, but in your code it would return `None`. Please note that  many of the issues listed above are not PyQt related: they are just basic python or general programming aspects (like your usage of `con1` that gets overwritten).